# Is it ethical to answer questions about homework for colleagues taking courses I've already completed?

Tags: ethics, homework, answering-questions

I receive many questions from colleagues about homework in a certain course which I took a while back. I try to answer them and help them solve homework which are very similar to the ones I did when I was taking the course. There is no TA for that course, so they come to me with their questions.

I am not sure if what I am doing is ethical. The professor doesn't know that I am doing this. Should I stop and tell him about this and see what he says?

Answer (score 21):

To "answer their questions" may mean different things, and some of them are OK, while others are not. E.g. answering questions like "What does this mean?" by explaining the thing in your own words is of course OK. However, solving their homework problems for them is not.

I guess, one can draw a line here: If you are **helping them to learn the topic** then it **is OK**. If you only try to **help them to pass the course without caring about their progress** in the topic, it **is not OK**.

So my advice would be: Focus on the topic itself when answering questions. Try to find out or guess what the instructor of the course wants the students to learn and help them to accomplish that.

Oh, and of course, asking the instructor is also OK.

Comment: I always thought this summed it up well: "What your friends learn is far more important than how they learn it." Giving them the answer is ok as long as they also understand the answer: the goal of the course is to increase knowledge, and as long as you're increasing their knowledge, there is no right or wrong. You teaching them is no different to the staff member teaching them, as long as they understand it at the end

Answer (score 7):

In most courses I've seen, there is usually some sort of policy regarding how and when to cite sources, where "sources" include people. If your course has such a policy, then it should be straightforward to answer whether what you're doing is ethical or not. If the instructor explicitly forbids collaboration on homework assignments, then you should probably not answer anything related to homework. However, if there is no explicit policy, then it is fully acceptable to either ask the professor (as Dirk mentions) or ask that you be cited as a source on the homework.

Personally, I only answer homework questions where there is at least some effort put into trying to solve the question(s) and/or not working on the exact problem in favor of a similar one. As such, I am not just giving away solutions, and I can usually focus more on the theory behind the problem than the problem itself. The downside is that it can be hard to come up with a related problem that is not trivially different from the "real" homework problem.

As an aside, this type of question comes up very frequently in various Stack Exchange Metas. If you search "homework questions" or "homework policy" on [Cross Validated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=homework+questions) or [Mathematics](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/search?q=homework+policy), for example, you'll see many discussion about what to do when posed with homework questions. I think a lot of the discussions might be relevant to you or anyone faced with a situation like you describe.

Answer (score 3):

I enjoy the Socratic method. I can walk somebody through a solution step by step without ever answering their question, by asking them questions that lead them to the next step on their own. This has been widely unpopular for me, because most people I surround myself with want instant gratification. When they see the solution, it makes perfect sense, and they feel like they "know that," but they were not able to synthesize the solution independently, and likely cannot do so later on, such as on an exam. Recognizing solutions and synthesizing them are different. I know very few people who want to endure the pain of learning something, and it sounds like the person using you as a crutch is using you from the way you narrate your situation. I see no harm in using the Socratic method and no need to tell anybody about it. Is the material on Khan Academy?

Comment: Now, I wish I had thought of using the Socratic Method when I was in a similar position, which was quite often back then.

Comment: It still depends, I believe, on whether the homework is part of the course assessment or not. If it is, then no matter how wise and wily you are, if you lead someone up the garden path to the solution (and especially if you can do so because you did similar assessment for the exact same course), then you risk subverting the intended assessment and they risk having cheated because they were helped on their assignment. If it isn't, then sure, when someone's definitely stuck on their homework then it's a great help to unstick them with the right question.

Answer (score 0):

If, after you are done helping, the person you helped could take a blank piece of paper and completely answer the question(s), then you've helped someone learn and that is good.

If, on the other hand, the person you've helped is parroting your words, formulas, algorithms, or whatever and cannot otherwise answer the question, then (depending on the policies of the course) both of you may have committed academic misconduct.  Regardless of policies, what you have done is unethical because you've deprived another student of an opportunity to learn.